# “None of” vs Negative Lookahead

Tags: php, regex

I try to find all `href` or `src` not starting with a slash or hash.

E.g.

```
<a href="img/foo.png"></a>      // should match
<a href='img/foo.png'></a>      // should match
<img src='img/foo.png'></a>     // should match
<a href="#"></a>                // should not match
<a href="/img/ajax.gif"></a>    // should not match
<img src='/img/ajax.gif'></a>    // should not match
```

---

I tried to solve it by using a [Negative Lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(href|src)=["']((?!\/)|(?!#)).*["']
```

[image]

But it matches everything...

[image]

---

Then I tried it it with the "None of" method:

```
(href|src)=["\'][^\/#].*['"]
```

[image]

[image]

This works. Why does the Negative Lookahead fail?

Comment: do not capture lookaheads [`(href|src)=["'](?![\/#]).*["']`](https://regex101.com/r/0ntRz2/4)

Comment: Please do not break the Stack Overflow site design by posting answers as comments.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but it sounds like you're overengineering the problem. a) Do you really need to use regex here? b) What stops you from just grabbing the values of the `href` and `src` attributes and checking whether they start with `#` or `/`?

Comment: @silkfire, I use the regex with Notepad++ to search my whole project for href and src not starting with slash (shouldn't target links like `href="#"` either.) so that I can fix the link to make it relative to the root, e.g. change `src="../../../../css/file.css"` to `src="/css/file.css"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `((?!\/)|(?!#))` part matches a position that is *either* not followed with a `/` *or* `#`, while `[^\/#]` matches a char that is *neither* `/` *nor* `#`.

You need to write the lookahead as `(?![\/#])`: a position that is not followed with `/` *nor* `#`.

A regex may look like

```
(href|src)=(["'])(?![\/#]).*?\2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF1dB6/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=(href%7Csrc)%3D(%5B%22'%5D)(%3F!%5B%5C%2F%23%5D).*%3F%5C2):

[image]

**Details**

- `(href|src)` - Group 1: either `href` or `src`
- `=` - a `=` char
- `(["'])` - Group 2: `'` or `"`
- `(?![\/#])` - the next char can't be `/` nor `#`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than linebreak chars,  as few as possible
- `\2` - backreference to Group 2, same value as captured into the group, `'` or `"`.